# Programmatically write text in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

Following text I want write in UITextView then how can I write it in UITextView

```
Provides freeze protection to -45°F to ensure a clean, clear windshield

    >Concentrated formula
    >Provides freeze protection to -45°F
    >Removes road film and bug splatter
    >Use year-round
    >Choose the freeze protection you need
    >Contains a special bittering agent
    >Harmless to car finishes when used as directed
```

I want a similar kind of structure in UITextView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format string like your requirement:

```
yourTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Provides freeze protection to -45°F to ensure a clean, clear windshield\n    >Concentrated formula\n    >Provides freeze protection to -45°F\n    >Removes road film and bug splatter\n    >Use year-round\n    >Choose the freeze protection you need\n    >Contains a special bittering agent\n    >Harmless to car finishes when used as directed"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set any text you want using:

```
yourTextView.text = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
```

So if you want to have the same structure that you show us:

```
yourTextView.text = @"Provides freeze protection to -45°F to ensure a clean, clear windshield\n\n >Concentrated formula\n >Provides freeze protection to -45°F\n >Removes road film and bug splatter\n >Use year-round\n >Choose the freeze protection you need\n >Contains a special bittering agent\n >Harmless to car finishes when used as directed";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this programatically.

```
textView.text = @"Type your text here"...
```

You can use \n for new lines and \t for tab bar space.

Try  this

Answer (score 0):

make use of `'\n'` for new line start and `'\t' (Escape sequences)` for tabbed space within the textview text.